# Python defaultdict get original dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Let's say we have:

```
from collections import defaultdict
original_dict = { 'somegroupofelements':{'name':1, 'group':1 ,'results':[1,2,3,4]}, 'somegroupofelements2':{'name':2, 'group': 2 ,'results':[1,2,3,4]}, 'somegroupofelements3':{'name':3, 'group':3 ,'results':[1,2,3,4]} }

new_dict = defaultdict(list)

for key, value in original_dict.iteritems():
    # i need to organize things grouped for making the right latex tables
    # and for updating some values...
    value['key']=key
    new_dict[value['group']].append(value)
```

I want that new_dict, after I've done my work, to be organized again just like the original_dict? Like reconstruct the original_dict from the new_dict.

Comment: So, what's wrong with your current code?

Comment: `original_dict` is not even a dict.

Comment: @Marcin: He wants to reverse the operation presented here.

Comment: Hi Marcin, There's nothing wrong in the code. I think I wasn't clear enough, sorry for that. I want after running that code, at the end of it, a way to organize new_dict just as the original_dict.

Comment: The line assigning to `original_dict` won't compile (are you trying to create a set of dicts? a list of dicts?). The `for` loop seems incorrect as well (need `iteritems()`?). And your loop throws away the value of `k`, so reconstructing it is impossible.

Comment: Also, what is the nature of the "organization" of the dicts? Why is this a problem, and what is the nature of the problem?

Comment: @Arthur: That code is badly broken. The definition `original_dict` is syntactically wrong, the `for` loop is semantically wrong and `original_dict['group']` should also be invalid. To me this only makes sense if `original_dict` is a list of dicts, in which case the loop would have to be `for v in original_dict: new_dict[v['group']].append(v)`

Comment: Sorry @interjay I corrected the code. The key is the name of the file I've opened. Marcin, I've tried to carry one more pair key/value so new_dict could be grouped again using that pair. That didn't worked so I went here see if someone have tried something like that.

Comment: @Arthur: It's still not valid. Please make it run properly.

Comment: @Arthur: It's still not valid. Did you actually try it?! Oh please don't ever post questions on SO of which you did not even test the code in advance. `original_dict['group']` should raise a `KeyError`. Also, I don't see how one would reconstruct the keys of `original_dict`, as you throw them away. The best thing you can get back is a list of items, like my answer suggests.

Comment: You should probably read http://sscce.org/ on what a good example is.  Until your example can be cut and pasted into an interpreter and it produces the output -- even if the output is an error message -- that you want to show people, it's not ready.

Comment: @Arthur: Now that you edited again, it should work, but the `v[k] = k` line isn't very helpful. What about `v['key'] = k`, so that the key is identifiable?

Comment: Sorry for all the trouble guys. I've pasted the code and it wasn't running at all. I'm trying the @NiklasB solution.

Comment: @Arthur: Man, now `k` is undefined... What are you even doing? Do you mean `v['key'] = key`?

Comment: @NiklasB. Now it's ok. I forgot to change the last 'k'.

Comment: @Arthur: No, it's still not okay. How would the reverse algorithm know which one is the key? It would be sensible to do `v['key'] = key` instead.

Comment: @NiklasB. I've got what you said now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you end up with a dictionary in the form:

```
>>> d = { 100 : [{'name':1, 'group':100, 'key':'group1'}, 
...              {'name':2, 'group':100, 'key':'group2'}],
...       200 : [{'name':3, 'group':200, 'key':'group3'}] }
```

Which can be transformed back into a dictionary using a dict comprehension:

```
>>> orig = { x['key']:x for v in d.values() for x in v }
>>> orig
{'group1': {'group': 100, 'name': 1, 'key': 'group1'}, 
 'group3': {'group': 200, 'name': 3, 'key': 'group3'}, 
 'group2': {'group': 100, 'name': 2, 'key': 'group2'}}
```

If you want, you can then delete the superflous `key` field of the items:

```
>>> for v in orig.values(): del v['key']
...
>>> orig
{'group1': {'group': 100, 'name': 1}, 
 'group3': {'group': 200, 'name': 3}, 
 'group2': {'group': 100, 'name': 2}}
```